# How do I get my expect statement to not output the stdout of the first command?

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo, expect

What I'm trying to do is execute an ssh command that prints out the `/etc/shadow` file.  Obviously that file requires root or `sudo` permission, and I don't have root creds, therefore I have to use `sudo`.

Here is the command I've worked out:

```
expect -c 'spawn -noecho ssh -q -t -S /tmp/t2.ssh dummy "sudo cat /etc/shadow";expect "assword"; send "password99\r";interact'
```

It outputs exactly what I need, but it also outputs the prompt for the sudo password on the very first line:

```
[sudo] password for student99:
root:$x$xxx:18029:0:99999:7:::
daemon:*:17575:0:99999:7:::
bin:*:17575:0:99999:7:::
sys:*:17575:0:99999:7:::
sync:*:17575:0:99999:7:::
```

Without using other programs (like grep, awk, tail, etc) is there a way to modify the `expect` command so that it prints only the output of the cat command and not the `[sudo] password for student99:` prompt?

**Solution:**
Thanks to @larsks, my final working command is:

```
expect -c 'spawn -noecho ssh -q -t -S /tmp/t2.ssh dummy "sudo cat /etc/shadow";log_user 0;expect "assword"; send "password99\r";interact'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable output logging by setting `log_user 0`.  From [the docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html):

```
log_user -info|0|1
    By default, the send/expect dialogue is logged to stdout (and a logfile if
    open). The logging to stdout is disabled by the command "log_user 0" and
    reenabled by "log_user 1". Logging to the logfile is unchanged.

    The -info flag causes log_user to return a description of the most recent
    non-info arguments given.
```

Comment: This is it!  Thank you!

My final command is:

expect -c 'spawn -noecho ssh -q -t -S /tmp/t2.ssh dummy "sudo cat /etc/shadow";log_user 0;expect "assword"; send "password99\r";interact'